# How does one capture vt100 responses in an ssh client to linux terminal

Tags: c, ssh, vt100

I have a text editor which is invoked in a session from the Windows 10 command prompt.

ssh user@linuxhost

If I invoke this command doit.sh

```
echo "echo X;^[[999;999H^[[6n"
```

then these characters are sent to the screen in accordance with the vt100 specification
(^[ signifies the ESC character with decimal code 27).

```
echo X;
:~$ ;75R
```

(The bell sounds)

After experimenting I think that bash is sounding the bell and the prefix of the response is lost.

I am not asking about this behaviour but I am asking how my text editor can by some device send ^[[999;999H^[[6n and capture the response ESC[{row};{col}R.